# CMake: How to add a dependency that is not a "link" dependency

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project configured by `CMake`. It has a program and a some shared libraries.

- Some shared libraries are linked by the program (using `target_link_libraries` statement).
- Some other shared libraries are not linked by the program, kind of plugins: they are loaded at runtime through `LoadLibrary` Win32 API.

We use Visual Studio 2015 as `CMake` target compiler. But from this IDE, when I start my program (press F5) after I modified some code, only the program and linked shared libraries are compiled. The "plugins" to be loaded at runtime are not compiled and so the code do not match the binary.

Is there a way to add a "build dependency", saying that some libraries should be compiled if out-of-date before a program is executed, even if this last one does not link them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a CMake command exactly for this purpose: [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/add_dependencies.html). It should do what you are looking for. Example:

```
add_executable(mainTarget SomeSource.cpp)
add_library(linkedLib SomeOtherSource.cpp)
add_library(libToBeLoaded MODULE MoreSource.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mainTarget PRIVATE linkedLib)

# This is it:
add_dependencies(mainTarget libToBeLoaded)
```

Comment: Might be nice to give him a little 3 line example

Comment: In CMake "plugins" are usually built as `MODULE` type of the library: `add_library(libToBeLoaded MODULE MoreSource.cpp)`. Since "plugin" is the main reason why `add_dependencies` is used instead of `target_link_libraries`, I would suggest to add `MODULE` keyword to the example code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: And if within the project the given library is both linked by a program and loaded at runtime by another (plugin), should it be SHARED or MODULE?

Comment: @jpo38: `MODULE` type of the library tells CMake (and the linker) that there is no need to find **all** symbols used by the library during the linking stage. As far as I understand, for **link** the library to your program the library should have all symbols found, either inside itself or in the other libraries it links to. In that case it is better to compile the library as SHARED.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the clarification